# How to match the data in the struct?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

If the **Set** function receives two inputs

1.["0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",50,"ROC","park"]

2.["0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",60,"AU","school"]

How can I return all the **time** in the struct, because I want to use that **time** to do some if-else statement?

For example, I want to use the **time** to do some matching, if there are 40 users to input their **time**, location and position, the **start** function will use the **time** to do some matching(if-else), then send the matching result to the user.

```java
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract matching {

    struct User {
        uint time;
        string location;
        string position;
    }
    User[] people; 

    mapping (address => User) user_mapping;
    address[] public userAccounts;

    function Set(address _address, uint _time, string memory _location, string memory _position) public {
        User storage users = user_mapping[_address];

        users.time = _time;
        users.location = _location;
        users.position = _position;

        userAccounts.push(_address) -1;
    }

    function getAccounts()public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return userAccounts;
    }

    function getInfo(address _address) view public returns (uint, string memory, string memory) {
        return (user_mapping[_address].time, user_mapping[_address].location, user_mapping[_address].position);
    }

    function countInfo() view public returns (uint) {
        return userAccounts.length;
    }
    function start() public{
     //Use the time that store in struct to do some matching
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to access the `time` property for all instances of `User` struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say why.

From the generality of the description, I get the impression that you are looking for a general method for ad-hoc queries as if it's convenient.

It's not. You have to anticipate every internal query the contract will need and construct the state organization accordingly. Have a look over here for some thoughts on this topic: https://medium.com/solidified/the-joy-of-minimalism-in-smart-contract-design-b67fb4073422

To identify users by time, possibly to decide if a transaction is acceptable, you could organize things with a mapping to help:

`mapping (uint=>address []) ...`

If the list is dynamic as I suspect might be the case, you will need a delete capability. Otherwise, pushing addresses to the array might be enough.

It's a general answer. I don't think it's possible to be more specific without more details.

Hope it helps.